# what protocol is used on transport layer for eDonkey?

Tags: p2p

Which protocol is used on transport layer for eDonkey?
Is it UDP or TCP, or both?
I haven't found out definitive answer from the protocol specification. Maybe I didn't dig deep enough.

Comment: Considering you transmit and recieve it would indeed be both.  I will not provide documentation since there really isn't a legit reason to use eDonkey.

Answer (score 0):

There is [The eMule Protocol Speciﬁcation](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/danss/p2p/resources/emule.pdf)